# What date format was this file I downloaded in?

Tags: file, html

I downloaded a HTML template as a ZIP a few years ago and one of the files was in this form:

20160822105352-testing-1.html

What sort of date format is that in, UNIX or some other?

Comment: 2016-08-22 10:53:52 ?

Answer (score 4):

That could match ISO 8601 without time zone.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601